# how to make categories line chart with nvd3

Tags: meteor, nvd3.js

i have explored for this packages, it hard for me.

1. let's say we had five category
2. I need each category will be as line graph

   Means:

   1. Computer have 300
   2. Laptop have 120
   3. Mouse have 400
   4. keyboard have 150
   5. speaker have 300

it should be one line graph only

Please help, it quite hard for me.

[image]

Comment: I've no clue as to what the final chart shall look like. Like the sketch you attached?

Comment: yes sir, i have tried many time and another explorer. still hard to find as example with using nvd3JS